# Page not loading with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am new to AJAX & trying to load a page (test.html) through ajax in to a DIV. I just want to know that is it possible to use AJAX without PHP server (which I am not using at present) or is there any error in the code:

My index.html file is as under:

```
<! doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hwcb.css">
</head>
<body>
      <input type="button" value="Load" class=”loadpage1”/>
       <div id="loadpagea1"></div>

  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="css.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

my test.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
We belongs to a great nation
</body>
</html>
```

main.js page:

```
$('.loadpage1').click(function(){
$.ajax({
url:'test.html',
success:function(data){
$('#loadpagea1').html(data);
}
});
});
```

Comment: inside success callback instead of `$('.loadpagea1').html(data);` try `$('#loadpagea1').html(data);` and instead of using ajax for loading static html try using `.load()` instead.

Comment: This code should be $('#loadpagea1') as id selector.

Comment: Already used but not working

Comment: Firstly let me know, your click event working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want to know that is it possible to use AJAX without PHP server

Assuming by this you mean without any server in general, then no it is not. You cannot make an AJAX request to the local file system as it will be blocked by the browsers' security settings.

You need to make the request to a server, either local or remote. I would suggest setting up an XAMP server for PHP, or IIS for ASP.Net.

Comment: I cannot use server as this is office computer, is there any way without server also, i.e. by changing browser setting etc.

Comment: @user3811050 I'm afraid not. Imagine if someone could get access to files on your local machine via AJAX. I'd have your bank details in an instant ;) You can install a server on that machine though - assuming you're allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.loadpage1').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                url:'test.html',
                success:function(data){
                var data = $(data);

                $('#loadpagea1').html(data.find('body').html());
                }
                });
                });

            })
```

Try this

Comment: @user3811050 
 
Sorry, I have edited my answer please check with this.And make sure that your index.html and test.html files are at same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var jqXHR = $.ajax({
        url: "/test.html",
        type: "get",
        contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
        }
    });
    $('#loadpagea1').html(jqXHR.responseText);
```

Comment: Check your file path is correct, try to use "/test.html" or "test/html".

Comment: Tried again but not working I have already shown my html file sir

Comment: Its working , its appending the html body text inside the div.

Comment: Still not working, this may be perhaps because I am not running it on server

Answer (score 0):

you have html syntax error, see quotes `class=”loadpage1”` change with `class="loadpage1"`